# Depth First Search returns only root value

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I am trying to get a list of values of the tree using DFS but I only get root's value. :(

```
def depthFirstSearch(root):
    output = []
    if root:
        output.append(root.value)
        depthFirstSearch(root.left)
        depthFirstSearch(root.right)
    return output
```

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

A bit late perhaps, but if you look at what you do it makes sense that only your `root` is returned.

Specifically, you append the `root.value` in the first iteration, then you run `depthFirstSearch` for both children (in a binary tree, presumably), but here's the thing: You just discard the result. It will *probably* work if you concatenate the results from both recursive calls to the output before returning.

That would get you something like:

```py
def depthFirstSearch(root):
    output = []
    if root:
        output.append(root.value)
        # use the += operator to concatenate the current output list and the new one from the subtree
        output += depthFirstSearch(root.left)
        output += depthFirstSearch(root.right)
    return output
```